# Android N showing warning alert in Zbar .SO File

Tags: zbar, android-7.0-nougat

> Hello All, I am facing issue on Android N with some warning alert about Zbar .SO File Like "has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.", Can you please any one help out this issue. but working fine upto Android 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I fixed the issue with the help of ndk-r10d generated libiconv.so file,Now it's working fine .

Comment: how did you generate the new .so file?

Comment: I did with latest version of NDK @LuciaBelardinelli